# Quickfix MarketDataIncrementalRefresh: Tag not defined for this message type

Tags: c++, quickfix, fix-protocol

I use Quickfix c++.
I receive FIX message from the server:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=312|35=X|34=17|49=CX|52=20150413-13:33:39.691|56=CACIB_MD2|262=1|9883=IDB|268=2|279=2|269=0|55=535791|270=15|271=1|272=20150413|273=13:28:07.653|59=0|126=20150413-21:56:46.201|290=1|9139=cacib_uat2|279=0|269=0|55=535791|270=17|271=1|272=20150413|273=13:33:39.660|59=0|126=20150413-21:56:46.201|290=1|9139=cacib_uat2|10=015|
```

and Quickfix automatically sends back to the server reject message (tag 55 not defined for this message type):

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=121|35=3|34=17|49=CACIB_MD2|52=20150413-13:33:39.755|56=CX|45=17|58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=55|372=X|373=2|10=044|
```

But this tag (55) is defined in the dictionary file:

```
  <message name='MarketDataIncrementalRefresh' msgcat='app' msgtype='X'>
   <field name='MDReqID' required='N' />
   <field name='CXMarketType' required='N' />
   <group name='NoMDEntries' required='N'>
     <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
   </group>
  </message>
  ...
  <field number='55' name='Symbol' type='STRING' />
  ...
  <field number='262' name='MDReqID' type='STRING' />
  ...
  <field number='268' name='NoMDEntries' type='INT' />
  ...
  <field number='9883' name='CXMarketType' type='STRING' />
  ...
```

And FIX options are:

```
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=./conf/fix42_dictionary.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
```

I don't understand why Quickfix decides that tag 55 (symbol) is not defined, when it is part of the group.

Can you please help?

Comment: You have user defined fields in your incoming message `9139`. Put `ValidateUserDefinedFields=Y` and check.

Comment: And, of course, make sure 9139 is added to the `NoMDEntries` (268) repeating group.

Comment: But I have a lot of user defined fields in this message and I don't them to be validated, as in this case I will have to specify all of them in the dictionary. If I put it to YES, it starts complaining...

Comment: If you don't validate how do you think Quickfix will understand the message, not by magic I presume. What if the other user sends across all user defined fields in the body, how do you intend to treat it ? You don't want to do the hard work of fixing up your configuration then you will continue getting this error.

Comment: @AndreyRubliov were you able to resolve this issue? Im experiencing something very similar right now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can't directly add groups to messages, it should be inside a component first

```
<message name='MarketDataIncrementalRefresh' msgcat='app' msgtype='X'>
    <field name='MDReqID' required='N' />
    <field name='CXMarketType' required='N' />
    <component name='NoMDEntriesComp' required='N' />
</message>

<component name="NoMDEntriesComp">
    <group name='NoMDEntries' required='N'>
        <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
    </group>
</component>
```

NoMDEntries type should be NUMINGROUP instead of INT

```
<field number='268' name='NoMDEntries' type='NUMINGROUP' />
```

Comment: You can directly add groups to messages.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.It is QuickFix incorrect reporting of the error. It is necessary to define the user defined fields in the FIX4?.xml. Define the fields in the  section and add them to the appropriate message as well.In your case 9883 is look like custom tag you have declared it but not defined in 35=X message properly. So if you use this custom tag in 35=X message inside NoMDEntries can solve your problem.

```
  <message name='MarketDataIncrementalRefresh' msgcat='app' msgtype='X'>
   <field name='MDReqID' required='N' />
   <group name='NoMDEntries' required='N'>
     <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
     <field name='CXMarketType' required='N' />
   </group>
  </message>
```